# Create Wistia model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, video-player, wistia

I am building currently an web app where **the admin will be able to post a title with a description and a link / embedded form of Wistia Video Player.**

Currently my setup is:

- Welcome Page
- Dashboard Page with Dashboard Controller (here only the admin will be
  able to post, edit things, all other users can only watch/comment)

**How do i create a model for this? Normally i would create a model like this:**

```
rails g model Video title:string description:text
```

**But how do i implement the Wistia Video Player, so that everytime the Admin creates a new post, he will be able to link/embedded a new video?**

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right then you want a permissions system that gives a user with the role "Administrator" the ability to create a new post with an embedded video? Normal "users" shouldn't be able to do this, right?
Do you already have a "Login system" or something familiar?
If not you should create a permissions system with sessions and stuff like that. (keyword: has_secure_password, BCrypt and sessions). 
After creating the system you could just use a before_action in your video controller or however you called it. With the before action you could simply check if the user that is logged in has the role "Administrator". If you only want to forbid embedding videos then just check the post before saving it to your table in the database.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! My login system / athentication system is already set up. The Admin is able to post things, a title and a description. But i also want him to be able to post wistia embedded videos in his post. I think i need to look further in the Wistia API.

Comment: I don't know anything about that API but you could create a template in your show.html.erb that takes a link and you could save that link in your table (when creating a new post) and insert it into your template when it's called. You could use an if -statement to check if there is a link in the table row to avoid getting errors. .. but therefore you need to change your Video model to: 
title:string description:text link_url :string (in your db / migrations file)
Drop a table using: "ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table)"